# JavaScript: Dynamically add new value to update JSON/ object

Tags: javascript, json

I have dynamically created object(predefined) and set value to 0 for all months(actually 12 months I have shown only 3 months) for all years(2 years, 2015 and 2014). So my data grid will look all months with 0 value.  see below code

```
 var arrayObj = [
               {"year" : 2015, "month" : "JAN", "value" : 0},
               {"year" : 2015, "month" : "FEB", "value" : 0},
               {"year" : 2015, "month" : "MAR", "value" : 0},
               {"year" : 2014, "month" : "JAN", "value" : 0},
               {"year" : 2014, "month" : "FEB", "value" : 0},
               {"year" : 2014, "month" : "MAR", "value" : 0}
             ];
```

Periodically, I will keep getting value of single month sometime in later in object format after form submit.

```
   eq. {"year" : 2015, "month" : "FEB", "value" : 2.33}
```

So my original object should also change accordingly, with javascript code. like below..

```
  var arrayObj = [
               {"year" : 2015, "month" : "JAN", "value" : 0},
               {"year" : 2015, "month" : "FEB", "value" : 2.33},
               {"year" : 2015, "month" : "MAR", "value" : 0},
               {"year" : 2014, "month" : "JAN", "value" : 0},
               {"year" : 2014, "month" : "FEB", "value" : 0},
               {"year" : 2014, "month" : "MAR", "value" : 0}
             ];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think map function would be ideal in this case. Please see the code segment below:

```
var src = [
           {"year" : 2015, "month" : "JAN", "value" : 0},
           {"year" : 2015, "month" : "FEB", "value" : 0},
           {"year" : 2015, "month" : "MAR", "value" : 0},
           {"year" : 2014, "month" : "JAN", "value" : 0},
           {"year" : 2014, "month" : "FEB", "value" : 0},
           {"year" : 2014, "month" : "MAR", "value" : 0}
         ];

var newRecord = {
"year": 2015,
"month": "FEB",
"value": 2.33
};

function updateJSON(src, newRecord) {
return src.map(function(item) {
  return (item.year === newRecord.year && item.month === newRecord.month) ? newRecord : item;
});
}
src = updateJSON(src, newRecord);
console.log(src);
```

Answer (score 1):

Walk the array, find the relevant month, and update its value:

```
var newData = { "year" : 2015, "month" : "FEB", "value" : 2.33 };

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var entry = data[i];

    if (entry.year == newData.year && entry.month == newData.month)
        entry.value = newData.value;
}
```

Your structure is not ideal for this kind of update, however. If you had 10.000 entries, you may need to examine all of them to update a single one.

You should instead organize data by year and month. For example:

```
var data = {
    '2015-FEB': 2.5
    '2015-MAR': 3.8
};
```

Updating this other structure is a single operation:

```
data[year + '-' + month] = value;
```

If you need your objects in the form you posted, you can have the best of both worlds:

```
var data = {
    '2015-FEB': { "year" : 2015, "month" : "FEB", "value" : 2.33 }
};
```

If you need them in sorted order, you can have **both** structures: the date-to-object map **and** the array, storing references to the same objects.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `filter` and find that object.

```js
var arrayObj = [{
    "year": 2015,
    "month": "JAN",
    "value": 0
}, {
    "year": 2015,
    "month": "FEB",
    "value": 0
}, {
    "year": 2015,
    "month": "MAR",
    "value": 0
}, {
    "year": 2014,
    "month": "JAN",
    "value": 0
}, {
    "year": 2014,
    "month": "FEB",
    "value": 0
}, {
    "year": 2014,
    "month": "MAR",
    "value": 0
}];

var newData = {
    "year": 2015,
    "month": "FEB",
    "value": 2.33
};

function findOneByMonthAndYear(arr, month, year) {
    return arr.filter(function(item) {
        return item.year === year && item.month === month;
    })[0];
}

var item = findOneByMonthAndYear(arrayObj, newData.month, newData.year);
item.value = newData.value;

console.log(arrayObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just select the cell from the array you want to update like so.

```
var n= { "year" : 2015, "month" : "FEB", "value" : 2.33 };

 var arrayObj = [
               {"year" : 2015, "month" : "JAN", "value" : 0},
               {"year" : 2015, "month" : "FEB", "value" : 0},
               {"year" : 2015, "month" : "MAR", "value" : 0},
               {"year" : 2014, "month" : "JAN", "value" : 0},
               {"year" : 2014, "month" : "FEB", "value" : 0},
               {"year" : 2014, "month" : "MAR", "value" : 0}
             ];

for (var z = 0; z < arrayObj.length; z++) {
   if(arrayObj[z].year="2015" && arrayObj[z].month="FEB")
        arrayObj[z].value=n.value;
}
```

Ofcourse,you can make it more dynamic as per your needs.